# Entity looks in different tables based on flag

Tags: hibernate, archive

We're using Hibernate in our server. There are certain entities that I'd like to reference in one table or another based on a switch/flag called `archived`. In other words, if the record has value of `archived=true`, look in the archived version of the table, otherwise look in the normal table. Both versions of the table (archived and not) have the same structure, we're only separating the data to speed the server up. However, a user can search both tables (from different views in front end), and we need to check one or the other table based on the archived flag.

How can this be done? I don't want to do two retrieves (check normal, then check the archive table if it's not there).

Thanks in advance,

Cez :)

Comment: What is the `archived` flag? Is it also one of the columns of your both tables?

Comment: @Chaitanya Yes, it is present on both tables and denotes if a row should be moved to the archived table. (So `archived` must be true for archived table and false for normal.)